# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Razor - Render Different HTML based on screen size

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, responsive-design

I want to render a different view (The razor html code that is rendered) depending on whether a user is viewing on mobile vs a PC or tablet.

For example, in the desktop version, a dashboard would display several charts and graphs as well as some totals in 2 rows of 8 columns (so 16 numbers).

Now for the mobile version, I want to reduce this (ie. only show maybe 2 rows of 4 columns, and hide 2 or 3 charts), this will give a cleaner look when viewing on mobile, though some detail would be lost.

How can I achieve this when a user hits a controller request? I figure I would need to pass in some parameter that specifies if this is a mobile view or not, but I would need that information before i can return a view. Is there a way of passing the screen resolution details to the controller? I would also want the controller to return a different view model than what the desktop version uses. (Less data = smaller viewmodel slice).

I'm aware that the recommended approach is using CSS media queries, but that really only applies to styling the existing layout, in this case here I want to alter the layout and reduce the content.

Here's a link to how the dashboard currently looks (it is not working for mobile correctly) - http://kaukasusinsurgency.com/Statistics/PlayerStats?playerUCID=a68afce32e6b1f57a6c8d10da24f1516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inform the server what the size of the browser client is - and, obviously, you cannot do this until you've made a request from the client to the server!

What I do is set a cookie in the client login page (or some other default or index page) using a spot of javascript (and [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie))

```
if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 992px)').matches) {
    Cookies.set(MEDIA_COOKIE, "wide");
}
```

and then read this on the server to determine what kind of content to return:

```
var media = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["media"];
if (media != null)
{
  if (media == "wide" && format != PageFormat.Wide)
    return View("MyPage", new Viewmodel(null));
}
```

This should work as most people don't change browser sizes, but if you need something that is responsive to changing browser sizes (ie during a session) then you'll have to update the cookie on every request.

I woulnd't use this for all page generation, but it can be very useful for not generating or reducing data in components.

Comment: Very clever solution!

Comment: We got an answer for you eventually! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the columns with col group like this, each column then will auto reduce with the size of the screen.

```
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 20%" />
<col style="width: 20%" />
<col style="width: 10%" />
<col style="width: 10%" />
<col style="width: 10%" />
<col style="width: 10%" />
<col style="width: 10%" />
<col style="width: 10%" />
</colgroup>
```

On W3 schools it has a more detailed explanation of [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp)
or you could use the viewport meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

mobile devices try to view a page like a desktop so it causes the screen to reduce or to zoom out. This will change the scale of a view to a [device]
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: That's what I am currently using with the style, currently on mobile the font is too large so it overlaps, I can make the font scale with the screen size in some way, but I wonder if the text would be too small. There's also the charts and graphs that I would need to figure out as well. I updated my question with a link to the dashboard for better idea.

Comment: Have you heard of a viewport meta tag. Have a look at putting it into the head html tag, its used top scale for mobile devices. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">